# Entity Framework Foreign Key DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm attempting to set up EF classes for a "code-first" approach, using the techniques outlined at the [EF page at Data Developer Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#Relationships), a related SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28482316/2658159), another SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448979/foreign-keys-in-entity-framework-4-1), and [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319366/EF-Code-First-Add-a-Foreign-Key-relationship) at CodeProject.com.

Two classes need to have one-to-many interaction using data annotations, specifically foreign keys.

Everything seems to be in order with my classes. I can perform a `context.Add()`, but when saving the changes through `context.SaveChanges()`, I get the following error message:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Machines' on type
>   'BacklogTracker.Models.EFModels.Customer' is not valid. The foreign
>   key name 'MachID' was not found on the dependent type.

**Why am I getting this error?**

My EF classes and foreign keys seem to be in order, based on the examples and techniques outlined in the links at the beginning of this question... but I can't figure out what's wrong. I'm a beginner at this, so it's very possible I'm missing something entirely.

I'm using VS2013 Express, .NET framework 4.5, EF 6.1.2. Here is code for the classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Machines = new List<Machine>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string MachID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MachID")]
    public virtual List<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Machine
{
    public Machine()
    {
        Customer = new Customer();
    }

    [Key]
    public string SN { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public int CustID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustID")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your codes, I suppose to that the relationship between customer and machine is `one-to-many`. `One` customer has `many` machines, and a machine is owned by one customer.

The machines are grouped into customer by a foreign key `CustID`. For those machines with the same `CustID`, they are under the same customer. If customer has a column named `MachID`, it will mean that a machine has many customers. It will conflict the fact that one customer has many machines.

@Nathan is right about to remove those codes.

If the `MachID` should exist, then you need to answer a question about what relationship holds between customer and machine. Is it `many-to-many`, `one-to-many` or `many-to-one` ? If the relationship is `many-to-many`, then your codes are totally wrong.

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    // One customer has many machines, so the `MachID` SHOULD NOT exist.
    // public string MachID { get; set; }
    // [ForeignKey("MachID")]
    public virtual List<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
}

public class Machine
{

    [Key]
    public string SN { get; set; }
    ...

    public int CustID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustID")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove:

```
public string MachID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("MachID")]
```

EF can infer the relationship from the machine side, if I understand you correctly

Also, shouldn't you have ID properties ?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't answer the question. Foreign keys are used because I don't use ID properties on some classes, ref the links in my question towards the top.

Comment: Each machine is associated with one customer, right ? So you can define a foreign key relationship here, but defining a foreign key from customer to machine does not make sense, as each customer can be associated with many machines. Or am I not understanding your intended model?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are annotating List rather than the Machine class itself.  I'm not sure if relationships can be defined on a collection like that.

Comment: That's better suited to be a comment!

Comment: Sorry!  I'm new to stack overflow and don't have enough reputation.